# LDAP query memberOf group with users from root domain

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

So I have a:

- (root) domain `lab.local` with a user `test1@lab.local`.
- Subdomain `inner.lab.local` with a group `testers` (`CN=testers,OU=Groups,OU=Domain Resources,DC=inner,DC=lab,DC=local`).
- In that subdomain I've created a user `test2@inner.lab.local`.
- I've added both `test1@lab.local` and `test2@inner.lab.local` to `testers` group
- In the subdomain, I've created a query `(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=CN=testers,OU=Groups,OU=Domain Resources,DC=inner,DC=lab,DC=local))`

Above query returns only `test2@inner.lab.local` (doesn't take a member from root domain: `test1@lab.local`).

I know the reason is that it's not a global catalog (it's marked as `universal`) thus `(...) membership in groups from other domains will not be listed (...)`

Is there any solutions for that? Is there anything I can do to get them both?

**EDITED** (to be more specific):

Here in root domain `mylab.local` (`192.168.1.168`) we can see a user `John` with `userPrincipalname` set to `john@mylab.local`:

[image: screenshot_of_root_domain]

Here we can see a subdomain `inner.mylab.local`(`192.168.1.169`). In here we have a group `testers` in `OU` called `Groups`. As you can see, in that domain we have a user `mike` defined. Both users `mike` (from `inner.mylab.local`) and `john` (from `mylab.local`) are members of the group `testers`:

[image]

My goal is to get both users based on group name. Thanks to Mr. Marcin answer, I know that I have to [Query the global catalog in the child domain](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/81e6d3a4-0dce-4d26-a33d-39521b5a0271/ldap-query-memberof-group-with-users-from-root-domain?forum=winserverDS). But, when connected to subdomain on port `3268`:

[image: screenshot_of_connection_properties_to_subdomain]

and queried users, I got only the one from subdomain:

[image: query_users_based_on_memberOf_attribute]

When I get the whole group, like this:

[image: query_group]

I can see both. But I need each user `userPrincipalName` attribute. So even If I do the second query to get info about each user from different domain, I am not able to get info about user:

[image: screenshot_query_user_based_on_dn]

So what I am doing wrong, that can't get user `john` (from different domain) when queried global catalog in child domain?

EDITED:
I am using `java` and `LdapTemplate`.

Comment: Two things: 1. Are you sure your 4th screenshot actually queried the global catalog? That should have worked.

Comment: 2. You are always better off reading the `member` attribute of the group rather than trying to query `memberOf` of users. If you tell us which programming language you're doing this in, we can help better.

Comment: "Are you sure your 4th screenshot actually queried the global catalog?"

third screenshot. I am connecting to the server (via LDAPAdmin) on port `3268`, so it should be GC, am I right ? (or no, maybe I am wrong, that's why I am here :))

Comment: I saw that, but I'm wondering if it actually did use the GC port for that query. It should work.

Comment: "2. You are always better off reading the member attribute". Yes I did change that, but I had trouble with getting `account name` from `SID`. That's my seconds question you answered just a moment ago. I take a bow, thanks.

Comment: :) I didn't realize that was you too. But the `member` attribute contains the `distinguishedName` of each member, which can be used to bind directly to each accounts too. So I'm not sure where you got the SIDs from.

Comment: above screenshots are just my configuration. There is different one where `member` attribute of a group returns: `CN=<SID>, DC=ForeignSecuirtyPrincipals,DC=...`.  so my `distinguishedName` of a group member is in that form. That is why I need translation

Comment: Ah, yes. When the member is on a trusted domain. Right. But that can only happen with domain local groups.

Answer (score -2):

I dont understand your problem but if you install JXplorer of help enough to see the structure and find out if there is something out of place.